# "change" in .live()

Tags: jquery

I excavated this thread: [JQuery live or something similar with .change()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343985/jquery-live-or-something-similar-with-change)

I have exactly the same problem as the person in that thread. I need to call change() on elements appended() in DOM.

I had success in using .live() but for clicks. Now I need to do the same things for the change in drop down list selection.

Ideally I don't want to use any plugins, as suggested in the topic.

Does anyone has any ideas how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of jQuery 1.7, `$.live()` is deprecated. You should use the new `$.on()` method:

```
$("form").on("change", "select", function(){
  alert ( this.value );
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ahikov/edit#javascript,html

Comment: Thanks, it works just fine. But how can I now get the value of option selected?

Comment: @Eleeist You can use `this.value` from within the handler.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with the "delegated" syntax.

```
$(function ()
{
    $(document).on('change', 'select', function ()
    {
        // your event handling code here
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the latest version of jQuery, I recommend you to use the "on" method instead of "click" "change" "live" etc.... try to attach your event from document:

```
    $(document).on('change', '.yourItem', function (e) {
        //Your code
    });
```